# How to keep popover alive while being hovered [for dynamic elements]

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have the following code which adds popover to dynamic elements successfully:

```
var selection = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
var image = '<img src="' + selection + '" />';
var previewLink = '<a class="show-popover" href="#" rel="popover" >(Hover to Preview)    </a>';

$('#headerBlock').append(previewLink);

$('body').popover({
     selector: '.show-popover',
     title: 'test',
     content: image,
     trigger: 'hover'
});
```

However, I cannot keep the popover alive when hovering. Below is my code, but it is not working:

```
$(".show-popover").popover({
     trigger: "manual",
     html: true,
     animation: false
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
     var _this = this;
     $(this).popover("show");
     $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
         $(_this).popover('hide');
     });
 }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
           $(_this).popover("hide");
       }
    }, 300);
});
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/KAvAZ/124/

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to the question (I hope it will help some others one day): http://jsfiddle.net/KAvAZ/127/

What I needed to do is to call `popover` method inside the `mouseenter` event of the link that is supposed to show the popover window. Since I need to cover the dynamic elements (i.e. added after DOM is loaded), I used `on` method:

```
    var selection = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
    var image = '<img src="' + selection + '" />';
    var previewLink = '<a class="show-popover" href="#" rel="popover" >(Hover to Preview)    </a>';
    $('#headerBlock').append(previewLink);


    $('body').on("mouseenter", '.show-popover', function() {
      var _this = this;

      $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
          return "Content";
        },
        title: function() {
          return "Title";
        }
      });

      $(this).popover("show");
      $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
      });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
      var _this = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
          $(_this).popover("hide");
        }
      }, 300);
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to hide the popover when the cursor leaves the link "(Hover to Preview)" and is not inside the popover?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selection = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
var image = '<img src="' + selection + '" />';
var previewLink = '<a class="show-popover" href="#" rel="popover" >(Hover to Preview)    </a>';
$('#headerBlock').append(previewLink);
$('body').popover({
  selector: '.show-popover',
  title: 'test',
  content: image,
  trigger: 'hover'
}).on("mouseenter", ".show-popover", function() {
    var _this = this;
    console.log("show")
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
        console.log("hide")
      $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
  }).on("mouseleave", ".show-popover", function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        console.log("time out")
        $(_this).popover("hide");
      }
    }, 300);
  });
```

The popover is build on body, so the `$(".show-popover")` can not trigger `.popover("hide/show")`

You need to bind the mouse event to the body to make it trigger correct DOM object

Comment: thanks for the answer! but, it does not seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/KAvAZ/125/

Comment: So what's your problem? The popover show when hover.

Comment: "How to keep popover alive while the popover is being hovered for dynamic elements"